# What is the English title of Anselm Grün's "Die Freude wird Vollkommen sein"?

Tags: german-to-english, book

Anselm Grün is a prolific author. My understanding of the meaning of the book titled **Die Freude wird Vollkommen sein** is *The Joy Will Be Complete*. This book was translated into Spanish under the title **La Alegria, Contra el Desconseulo de nuestro Tiempo**, which I think means something like *Joy against the Dispair of our time*. I have looked for Anselm Grün+Joy, Anselm Grün+Happiness, but I cannot figure out what this book translated into English would be published as. Can anyone tell me?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I guess the title alludes to Philippians 2,2, which reads in German:

> dann macht meine Freude dadurch vollkommen, dass ...

The English Standard Version has:

> complete my joy by ...,

so your translation is fine.

Grün's German publisher Herder translates the title as

> Joy will be perfect

(see herder.de/foreign_rights) and informs us that the Hungarian, Italian, Polish, Slovenian, Spanish (AR), Spanish (ES) rights of the book have been sold - no mention of an English translation.

Comment: Thank you. Your answer and [this Herder link](http://www.herder.de/foreign_rights/foreign_rights/backlist/theology_religion_spirituality/details_html?k_tnr=28510&onl_struktur=1673817&sort=2&query_start=199) was helpful :)

Comment: @CanadianGirlScout Don't forget to accept the Answer by clicking on the green check mark :)

Comment: Hi @EugeneSeidel Thanks, I try not to accept answers before 24 hours have gone by. This way, the other half of the world also gets the chance to read the question & answer it before the green checkmark gets assigned ;) Have no fear, if no one finds a copy in English within a week or so, then I will click this answer as accepted.

Comment: @CanadianGirlScout: Afaik you can always reassign the check-mark later, if a better answer occurs.

Comment: @userunknown Yes, but marking an answer as accepted decreases the likelihood of others 1) reading the question 2) posting a better answer.

Comment: Don't worry, everyone, I will not abandon the question ;)

Comment: @CanadianGirlScout: Hier ist so wenig los, dass man jede Frage liest. Dass jmd. von existenten Antworten abgeschreckt werden könnte eine bessere zu schreiben, wenn eine davon akzeptiert wurde, halte ich für ausgeschlossen. Man müsste als Hauptmotivation diesen Taler im Auge haben, und zweitens nicht wissen, dass dieser umgewidmet werden kann. Wer aber rein auf dieses Bonbon fixiert ist, der wird wohl auch die zugehörigen Regeln kennen.

Comment: Hi @userunknown It is an [issue](http://meta.genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/1/why-are-we-accepting-answers-so-fast) that is widely discussed. Anyways, it's good to remind people that they can accept answers if they are happy with them, especially newbies. I didn't understand all that you wrote: "Taler im Auge" is this like _point of view_ or like _keep this at the front of your mind_? And the bonbon bit, were you referring to rep? I didn't get it. Entschuldigung, mein Deutsch ist nicht so gut. We could move this to chat if you want ;)

Comment: Taler and Bonbon refer to the round emphasized check mark. `Im Auge haben` means `to have in mind`. We can delete it, if you like. :)

Answer (score -1):

"The joy will be unflawed" (or completed)
I am not sure about the context, but this seems accurate.

Comment: Welcome to German Language and Usage! Technically there is nothing wrong with your Answer but if you read through the Opening Question (OQ), the first Answer, and the comments below, I think you will agree that the Asker is looking for something more than just a guess regarding how the title might be translated.